# LPCSTR, TCHAR, String

Tags: string, visual-c++

I am use next type of strings:
LPCSTR, TCHAR, String i want to convert:

1. from TCHAR to LPCSTR
2. from String to char

I convert from TCHAR to LPCSTR by that code:

```
RunPath = TEXT("C:\\1");
LPCSTR Path = (LPCSTR)RunPath;
```

From String to char i convert by that code:

```
SaveFileDialog^ saveFileDialog1 = gcnew SaveFileDialog;
saveFileDialog1->Title = "Сохранение файла-настроек";
saveFileDialog1->Filter = "bck files (*.bck)|*.bck";
saveFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch = TEXT("");
if ( saveFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK ) {  
    wch = PtrToStringChars(saveFileDialog1->FileName);
} else return;
ofstream os(wch, ios::binary);
```

My problem is that when i set "Configuration Properties -> General 
Character Set in "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" the first part of code work correctly. But the second part of code return error C2440. When i set "Configuration Properties -> General 
Character Set in "Use Unicode" the second part of code work correctly. But the first part of code return the only first character from TCHAR to LPCSTR.

Comment: If you have UNICODE enabled in your build, then most of the Windows APIs are `#define`-ed to their wide-character versions. The T-types (e.g. `TCHAR`, `LPCTSTR`, etc) are mapped to `wchar_t` and `const wchar_t *` when UNICODE is defined. Otherwise they are mapped to `char` and `const char *`. If you're definitely programming in UNICODE, then you can just use things like `WCHAR` and `LPCWSTR`, avoiding the T-types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you need to be using Unicode the whole way through.

LPCSTR is a *"Long Pointer to a C-type String"*.  That's typically not what you want when you're dealing with .Net methods.  The *char* type in .Net is 16bits wide.

You also should not use the *TEXT("")* macro unless you're planning multiple builds using various character encodings.  Try wrapping all your string literals with the _W("") macro instead and a pure unicode build if you can.

See if that helps.

PS.  [std::wstring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt3s3k55.aspx) is very handy in your scenario.

**EDIT**

You see only one character because the string is now unicode but you cast it as a regular string.  Many or most of the Unicode characters in the ASCII range has their same number as in ASCII but have the second of their 2 bytes set to zero.  So when a unicode string is read as a C-string you only see the first character because C-strings are null ( zero ) terminated.  The *easy* ( and wrong ) way to deal with this is to use std:wstring to cast as a std:string then pull the C-String out of that.  This is not the safe approach because Unicode has a much large character space then your standard encoding.

Comment: I code in c++ with using .net i want to run programm and use WinExec function first parameter its the LPCSTR, have there is some similar function in .NET?

Comment: You have to consider that the 16bit Unicode string may represent a string that *cannot* be represented as a 8bit ASCII string.  But if you are willing to take the chance you can use the std::wstring constructor to create a wstring object then cast that to a std::string and use the c_str() method in that to get the LPCSTR.